# Tag manifest attribute package has invalid character '_' even after removing said character

Tags: android

I am working in Android 2.3.3, and have run into this error: "Tag manifest attribute package has invalid character'_'. Initially, I was getting this error because my package name contained an underscore (com.isco_pipe.www.fieldtechapp). I have since renamed the package and removed the underscore (as you can see in the manifest file below). But the error persists upon an attempt to rebuild. Any thoughts?

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.iscopipe.www.fieldtechapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.iscopipe.www.fieldtechapp.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Note: I previously asked a question about not being able to debug my app on my device (running Android Studio on a virtual machine). I am now attempting to setup and run my app in Android Studio directly on my Windows laptop to see if I can run the app on an emulator and debug from there. [Unable to attach debugger to Android process in Android Studio 2.3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45465553/unable-to-attach-debugger-to-android-process-in-android-studio-2-3-3)

Comment: check your **build.gradle** file also, what you gave for **applicationId**

Comment: Gah! Totally forgot to check that. That was the issue, thank you! Make your comment an answer, and I will choose it as the most helpful. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `build.gradle` file also, what you gave in `applicationId`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are editing the proper file. Android Studio has the **absolutely aggravating** "feature" where certain errors cause a file in `build/` to pop up in the editor. In your case, it would be a merged manifest, not your actual manifest. Editing files in `build/` will have no effect, as they get re-created on each build. So, make sure that you have modified your actual manifest (e.g., `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`).